# How to send two different ArrayList from a Servlet to a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I'll try to be clear in a few lines, showing only the essential code.
As I said in the title, I have to send two arraylists from a servlet to a JSP page. Unfortunately, I don't know how to send multiple arraylists to a JSP, but I know how to send one only. I usually use this procedure:

example

```
ArrayList<ClassA> array_A = new ArrayList<ClassA>();

// [...] After some operations and have filled the array_A with objects of class ClassA

ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
request.setAttribute("Attribute", array_A);
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/MyJSP.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
request.getSession().removeAttribute("Attribute");
```

This procedure allows me to send one arraylist to a JSP page. How can I send two different arraylist? For example, I need to send these two arraylist:

```
ArrayList<ClassA> array_A = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
ArrayList<ClassB> array_B = new ArrayList<ClassB>();

// [...] After some operations and have filled array_A with objects of class ClassA 
// & array_B with objects of class ClassB
```

How can I send these two arrays from the servlet to the JSP page? Could you kindly share me the code? I'm sorry if I wasn't so rigorous.

Comment: Put the other one in a second request attribute, with a different name.

Comment: @JBNizet just add another request.setAttribute ("Attribute_two", array_B); immediately after the first?

Comment: After, or before, it doesn't matter. A request has many attributes. An attribute has a name, and a value which can be anything. And you end up forwarding the request to the JSP, which can thus get all the attributes, stored before by the servlet, from the request. That's basically like putting all kinds of things in a box, then sending the box to someone else.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it was very helpful to reach the solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
request.setAttribute("array_A", array_A);
request.setAttribute("array_B", array_B);
```

---

within `jsp` (when using `jstl` core library, with prefix `c`:

```
<c:forEach var="itemA" items="${array_A}">
      <!-- some code here -->
</c:forEach>
```

and

```
<c:forEach var="itemB" items="${array_B}">
      <!-- some code here -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, problem solved :-)